# Will google blacklist my website for pasting relevant but duplicate articles?

Tags: seo, google

I work at a small startup, and we are struggling to get high ranks on google, in searches relevant to our website.

Since "content is king" when it comes to SEO, we want to add articles to our website that are relevant to our company inorder to rank higher on google searches.

We have already had a few newspapers make articles about us, and we want to add these articles to our website (we have permission from the publisher).

The question is will google blacklist us, for duplicating content from other websites (i.e the newspapers website where our article is as well), or reward us for making new relevant content on our website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content is an exact copy of that on the newspaper's website, then yes, Google will penalise your website for plagiarism.

You can, however, use canonical tags to mark one of the web pages as the original and the other one as the duplicate of the same content, that way the duplicate page won't get much benefits but would avoid penalty.(Remember that the page marked as the original one would get the benefits of ranking)

A better way is:

1. Create original content for your own website.
2. Share the snippets of that article with media/news companies and other websites.
3. Ask them to share those snippets on their websites with a backlink to your website to read the full story.

This way you get the benefits of the content as well as a backlink which will help you rank better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!